# Ionic AngularJS from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Im trying to have an item populated from a JSON file with angularJS. I need it to populate the "words" key from an id.  If they select id 2 then get the "words" key from that section of JSON.

Here is my code.

```
app.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Areas', function($scope, $stateParams, Areas) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.times = 0;
    $scope.postsCompleted = false;

    // load more content function
    $scope.getPosts = function() {
        Areas.getPosts()
            .success(function(data) {
            //          $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(data.areas);
            $scope.items = data.areas;
            // debugger;
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            $scope.times = $scope.times + 1;
            if ($scope.times >= 4) {
                $scope.postsCompleted = true;
            }
        })
            .error(function(error) {
            $scope.areas = [];
        });
    }

    // pull to refresh buttons
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        $scope.times = 0;
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.postsCompleted = false;
        $scope.getPosts();
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    }
}])
```

and my JSON

```
{
    "areas": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "pano": "data/guides/traxx/SteamPower.jpg",
        "words": "CH 1: The Traxx",
        "climbs": [{
            "_id": 1,
            "rating": 2,
            "description": "Severoof."
        }, {
            "_id": 2,
            "rating": 1,
            "description": "the wall behind the Railside problem."
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "pano": "data/guides/traxx/CH2/overviewTopo2.jpg",
        "words": "CH 2: Trackside Roofs",
        "climbs": [{
            "_id": 1,
            "overviewImage": "data/guides/traxx/CH2/mainTopo.jpg",
            "description": "Just past the main Traxx area is a hi."
        }, {
            "_id": 2,
            "image_thumb": "http://1.bp.blogspot.com",
            "title": "Trackside Arete V2",
            "description": "Start low near the right-center ofc."
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": 3,
        "pano": "data/guides/traxx/CH3/overviewTopo3.jpg",
        "words": "CH 3: The Trenches",
        "climbs": [{
            "_id": 1,
            "description": "Climb the nice wall on the downhill."
        }, {
            "_id": 2,
            "description": "Climb lone crack where two"
        }]
    }]
}
```

and the template

```
<ion-view view-title="Beta">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="doRefresh()">
        </ion-refresher>

        <p>Test to see what's here</p>

        <a ng-repeat="item in items">
            <p class="padder">{{item.words}}</p>
        </a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

So right now words for every id are being duplicated.  So I get all three ids "words" repeated.  So three "words" appear in the template.  I just need one "words" per id.  So only one should show up on that page.  But if I access another id id 2's "words" should show up.

Thanks so much

Comment: Off topic: You're missing a few non-critical (but advisable) semicolons. I suggest a run through JSHint.

Comment: That's odd. Everything looks fine to me. Can you throw it into a fiddle demo?

Comment: Have you tried `"... item in items track by $index"`? It shouldn't be necessary if your IDs are unique, but....